# C-style enum in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, enums

In C, we define enum this way:

```
enum E {
    E0,
    E1,
    E2 = 3,
    E3
};
```

Note `E2 = 3` expression, the enum type result in `E0 == 0, E1 == 1, E2 == 3, E3 == 4`.

In Haskell, we have no way to specify the enumeration in the declaration. The only way to implement discontinuous enumeration is implementing `Enum` class manually.

Is there any convenient way to do this?

I've write a [demo](https://gist.github.com/qzchenwl/4d8ca789bdaabaa073e5) using Template Haskell to generate the `Enum` instance.

```
data E = E0
       | E1
       | E2_3
       | E3
       deriving Show

enum ''E
```

I wonder if there are libraries trying to fill this gap?

Comment: What underlying problem do you want to solve?

Comment: @Franky, I'm trying to parse an binary file, generated by a program written in C.

Comment: @wenlong: could you use c2hs to generate the enum type?

Answer (score 6):

You can whip up something small & simple using Template Haskell's `reifyAnnotations` feature.

First, we need to define an annotation type to hold enum values:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
module Def where

import Data.Data

data EnumValue = EnumValue Int deriving (Typeable, Data)
```

Second, we need a bit of TH code to consume these annotations and turn them into `Enum` instance definitions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, QuasiQuotes #-}
module TH where

import Def
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Control.Monad
import Data.List (mapAccumL)
import Data.Maybe

enumValues :: [(a, Maybe Int)] -> [(a, Int)]
enumValues = snd . mapAccumL (\next (x, mv) -> let v = fromMaybe next mv in (v+1, (x, v))) 0

enumFromAnns :: Name -> Q [Dec]
enumFromAnns name = do
    TyConI (DataD _ _ _ cons _) <- reify name
    eVals <- fmap enumValues $ forM cons $ \(NormalC conName []) -> do
        anns <- reifyAnnotations (AnnLookupName conName)
        let ev = case anns of
                [EnumValue ev] -> Just ev
                [] -> Nothing
        return (conName, ev)
    [d|
     instance Enum $(conT name) where
       fromEnum = $(lamCaseE [match (conP c []) (normalB $ lift v) [] | (c, v) <- eVals])
       toEnum =  $(lamCaseE [match (litP . IntegerL . fromIntegral $ v) (normalB $ conE c) [] | (c, v) <- eVals])|]
```

And then finally we can use it (via a [small workaround to make sure the usage is in a new declaration group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562244/retrieving-annotations-from-the-same-module?noredirect=1#comment54903557_33562244)):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module AnnotatedEnumExample where

import Def
import TH

data E = E1
       | E2
       | E42
       | E43
       deriving Show

{-# ANN E1 (EnumValue 1) #-}
{-# ANN E42 (EnumValue 42) #-}

-- Force new declaration group
return []

enumFromAnns ''E
```

Example usage:

> ```
> *AnnotatedEnumExample> map fromEnum [E1, E2, E42, E43]
> [1,2,42,43]
> *AnnotatedEnumExample> map toEnum [1, 2, 42, 43] :: [E]
> [E1,E2,E42,E43]
> ```