# Retrieving annotations from the same module

Tags: haskell, annotations, template-haskell

Suppose I define my own annotation type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
module Def where

import Data.Data

data MyAnn = MyAnn Int deriving (Show, Typeable, Data)
```

and some Template Haskell function to access it:

```
module TH where

import Def
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax

myAnn :: Name -> Q Exp
myAnn name = do
    [MyAnn x] <- reifyAnnotations (AnnLookupName name)
    lift x
```

I would now like to use it like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Client where

import Def
import TH

x :: ()
x = ()
{-# ANN x (MyAnn 42) #-}

y :: Int
y = $(myAnn 'x)
```

But this fails because the `myAnn` invocation in the definition of `y` gets an empty list from `reifyAnnotations`.

It works if I split `Client` like this:

```
module Client1 where

import Def

x :: ()
x = ()
{-# ANN x (MyAnn 42) #-}

{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Client2 where

import Client1
import TH

y :: Int
y = $(myAnn 'x)
```

Is there a way to get something like the monolithic `Client` module to work?

Comment: Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561183/c-style-enum-in-haskell) for which I had an idea for a neat annotations-based solution.

Comment: It's more of a workaround, right?  Maybe someone has a real solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be expected behavior according to [the docs](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.3/docs/html/users_guide/):

> Accordingly, the type environment seen by `reify` includes all the top-level declarations up to the end of the immediately preceding declaration group, but no more.

An effective workaround for your problem is to 
force the start of a separate declaration group by including an empty top-level declaration splice, i.e. just

```
$(return [])
```

Comment: Edited from @DominiqueDevriese's helpful comment.